# Strange Maven exception building WAR

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven project which was working just fine until I added some new static resource files in `src/main/webapps/resources`.

This directory already contained subdirectories `js`, `img`, and `css`, now I added a new subdirectory `instructions` into which I added 3 pdf files, which are to be downloadable from deployed the application.

When I run the mvn build, I now get this exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) on project jpa: 
Error assembling WAR: resources/instructions/entrance.pdf not found. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: 
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) on project jpa: 
Error assembling WAR: resources/instructions/entrance.pdf not found.
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(MojoExecutor.java:365)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:199)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
```

It seems to be complaining that one of the files I just added is not there, when it most certainly **is**, why is that? And secondly, why should it care?

**EDIT**

`pom.xml` added. Many of the dependencies omitted otherwise it's very long.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>nick</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpa</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jpa</name>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.27</mysql.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- many dependencies omitted for brevity -->

</dependencies>

<build>

  <filters>
    <filter>src/main/filters/${profile.id}.properties</filter>
  </filters>

  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
  </resources>

  <plugins>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

  </plugins>

</build>

<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
            <server>tomcat8080</server>
            <path>/</path>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
      <profile.id>dev</profile.id>
    </properties>  
  </profile>
</profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: Post your whole POM.

Comment: And post the complete console log and stack trace.  However, `Error assembling WAR: resources/instructions/entrance.pdf not found.` looks pretty specific to me.

Comment: Yes but the file IS there

Comment: Hum, your POM doesn't even have the war plugin declared. This exception cannot be thrown with what you posted. I suggest you make a [mcve].

Comment: OK solved it - if I remove the file, it works. I can only assume it's choking on the file, maybe it is corrupt in some way.